# Firebase and react one-to-many relationship to save on firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, foreign-keys, one-to-many

How do you make a relationship in firebase and use the fields? I'm picking up here. I'm working with firestore here and I made relationships like this:

[image]

Where I have the collection of answers and it has serviceId collaboratorId and tokenId each of these there is a foreign key of the other collections that you can see in the image. I don't know if this is right, but assuming it's right anyway, how do you use this in React? When it was all string I could add it, now that it's changed to a reference it doesn't work anymore :(

To add I was doing this:

```
async function handleSubmitResult(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    await createFormSchema
      .validate({
        name,
        service,
        collaborator,
      })
      .then(() => {
        addDoc(answersCollectionRef, {
          name,
          service,
          collaborator,
          answer1,
          answer2,
          answer3,
          answer4,
          comment,
          createdAt: new Date().toString(),
        });
        console.log("SALVO NO FIREBASE! ");

        // A temporary fix to clear fields of the form
        document.getElementById("form-rating").reset();

        setName("");
        setService("");
        setCollaborator("");
        setAnswer1(0);
        setAnswer2(0);
        setAnswer3(0);
        setAnswer4(0);
        setComment("");

        navigate("/thanks");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        toast.error(error.message, {
          theme: "colored",
        });
      });
  }
```

This works perfectly when it was a string, but now that the fields have changed to the references of the collections I mentioned, I can no longer save it the way I want it in the firestore.

**---- After edit my question ------**

And when I edit my save method to:

```
async function handleSubmitResult(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    await createFormSchema
      .validate({
        name,
        service,
        collaborator,
      })
      .then(() => {
        addDoc(answersCollectionRef, {
          name,
          serviceId: service,
          collaboratorId: collaborator,
          answer1,
          answer2,
          answer3,
          answer4,
          comment,
          createdAt: new Date().toString(),
          tokenId: token,
        });
        console.log("SALVO NO FIREBASE! ");

        // A temporary fix to clear fields of the form
        document.getElementById("form-rating").reset();

        setName("");
        setService("");
        setCollaborator("");
        setAnswer1(0);
        setAnswer2(0);
        setAnswer3(0);
        setAnswer4(0);
        setComment("");

        navigate("/thanks");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        toast.error(error.message, {
          theme: "colored",
        });
      });
  }
```

It doesn't show any errors, it now is saving, but it saves as a string. Wouldn't it be correct to save the ID, given that I'm doing a one-to-many relationship? That's what I can't understand...

My firebase looks like this after saving:

[image]

------ Add ID of the document Service

Here is my Service, how get id document?

[image]

Comment: "I can no longer save it the way I want it in the firestore" Why not? What about the code you shared is keeping you from doing so? Is there an error message?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It says that the fields of serviceId, tokenId etc do not exist in firebase. However, even if you change the function by putting these fields in the add method, it doesn't save. And if I don't change the field, it saves it, but as a string and not as a foreign key

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact error message you get, and where it comes from in your code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Edited! Please helpe me. I'm really not able to understand relationship in firebase

Comment: There's no need to plea for help. I'm here, I'm trying. --- What field in that saved document is what you're asking about though? The `answer1` to `answer4` fields look like numbers to me at first glance.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The fields answers1 to 4, comment, name and createAt are ok. The problem is the serviceId, tokenId and colllaboratorId fields, they are being saved as a string, but they should be Ids, as they are foreign keys from the other collections. It is not?

Comment: I can't see from the code you shared what data type your `comment`, `name`, etc are. But if you want to store them as reference to other documents in the database, you'll have to make sure they are a `DocumentReference` to that document in your code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My repo is thes: https://github.com/eltonsantos/avaliation-system-react

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a reference to another document in the database, make sure that the value you pass in your code is a `DocumentReference` object to that document.

E.g. say that you want the `name` field to be a `DocumentReference` to the `Users` collection, that'd be something like:

```
addDoc(answersCollectionRef, {
  name: new DocumentReference(db, "Users", "idOfUserDocument"),
  ...
});
```

Comment: How do I get this "idOfUserDocument"? Example, in my case, I have a Collection Service, in this collection, I only have the capo name. So it would be like this: serviceId: DocumentReference(db, "Service", "name"), because if this idOfUserDocument is the id of the Collection itself, then two doubts arise: how to make it dynamic (because if it is the id, it will leave in hard code isn't it?) and the other question is how will this idOfUserDocument know exactly which field I want to get?

Comment: I tried it: serviceId: DocumentReference(db, "Service", doc.id), but doesnt work and given this error: Class constructor ya2 cannot be invoked without 'new'. I declared it: import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  doc,
  DocumentReference,
  getDocs,
} from "firebase/firestore";

Comment: That last one is a mistake in my code, so add the `new` that the error message complains about. --- On your first comment: it's hard for me to answer, but to add a document reference to the database you have to know what document to link to. If you don't know the ID of the document, but *do* know something else that uniquely identifies it, you can use a query to look up the matching ID.

Comment: I add image collection service, how I get id this?

Comment: Doest work :( DocumentReference(db, "Services", doc.id)

Comment: "Doest work" is hard to help with.